# Selenium determining whether a select option is visible

Tags: java, selenium, html-select

I am trying to pick an option within a select element depending on whether it is visible or not.

Is there anyway to determine whether options within selects are visible? They have that attribute in the CSS, but selenium doesn't have a `.isDisplayed` method for `Select` elements.

```
    // Select page role permission
    Select pageRole = new Select (driver.findElement(By.id("page_roles")));
    pageRole.selectByIndex(1);
```

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML and the error stack trace

Answer (score 2):

We can check directly with option locator, to check visiblity like below,

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#page_roles option[value='1']"))
```

But isDisplayed() will throw exception if not present. We have to check the presence of element by checking the size in findelements.

So you can make condition something like this

**Select by option:**

```
if(driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#page_roles option[value='1']")).size() > 0){
    Select pageRole = new Select (driver.findElement(By.id("page_roles")));
    pageRole.selectByIndex(1);
}
```

**Select by visible text:**

```
   String userRole="Admin";
    if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//[@id='page_roles'/option[text() ='"+userRole+"']")).size() > 0){
        Select pageRole = new Select (driver.findElement(By.id("page_roles")));
        pageRole.selectByVisibleText(userRole);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by visible. If you mean `.isDisplayed()` then all `OPTION`s are visible (according to Selenium) whether they are actually visible or not.

An example, go to http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/dropdown and see that there is a `SELECT` element on that page that contains two `OPTION`s, 'Option 1' and 'Option 2'. If you locate them using Selenium and return `.isDisplayed()` they will both return `true` even though in the default state neither of them are selected (and are not visible to the user).

I *think* what you really are looking for is do they exist in the list of options. If this is what you mean, we can determine that. The function below was built to run against the link above. It gets the list of options in the dropdown, extracts the text from each, and then compares the string you pass in to see if it is an available option.

```
public static boolean optionExists(String option)
{
    return new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("dropdown"))).getOptions().stream().map(e -> e.getText()).collect(Collectors.toList())
            .contains(option);
}
```

You can use it like this.

```
String option = "Option 3";
if (optionExists(option))
{
    new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("dropdown"))).selectByVisibleText(option);
}
```

You can chain these together, as needed. You could also use the code in optionExists in a method that sets the value based on a supplied List of strings. It could loop through the List, check each one to see if it exists, and then select the first one found... or something like that. I'll leave that to you...

Answer (score -1):

you can use xpath for this

This should work:

```
var select = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='page_roles' and not(contains(@style,'display:none'))]");
//check if select is not null here
Select pageRole = new Select (select);
pageRole.selectByIndex(1);
```

Comment: This won't work because typically the SELECT and OPTIONs don't contain the `display:none` style. Also, if it doesn't exist, it will throw.

Answer (score -2):

You can try creating a list of the options that contains the attribute you mencioned:

```
 List<WebElement> visibleOptions = pageRole.findElements(By.cssSelector("Visible css class"));
```